# Selenium stop processing requests

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I will take from html file in previous operations option ids and i will store them into a list.

Then for each member of a list try to open page lile : www.xxx.xxx/en/account/service/SERVICEID

for first valid element page is opened but then browser will cease any activity... and i will get this

org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 3.28 seconds

```
   public class testy2{
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private List<WebElement> serviceList;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.fastgsm.com";

   // driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS);


}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    //Open page and set up login
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/en/account/login");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("selenium@account");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("1Selenium");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).submit();


    serviceList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='token_id']/option"));


    for (WebElement service : serviceList) {

        if(!service.getAttribute("value").contains("-")){
        String test = service.getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println("Checking service name : " + service.getAttribute("value") + ",on page " + (baseUrl + "/en/account/service/"+service.getAttribute("value")) );

        driver.get(baseUrl + "/en/account/service/"+test);

        System.out.println("Service name : " + service.getAttribute("value") +"status : OK");

        }
        else{
        System.out.println("ERROR : INVALID SERVICE NAME");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You'll want to build an array or list serviceId of attributes first.  Then iterate through serviceId.  The issue you're having is that serviceList (and by extension, service) are references to the very first page.  When you access a second page, all of those references are now "stale".

Comment: Ok... and how exactly should i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what language you are using, so this is going to be pseudo-code:

```
serviceList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='token_id']/option"));

// create a string array of the count of elements in serviceList
private string[] serviceIDs = new string[serviceList.Count];
private int i = 0;

// populate serviceIDs with the attribute "value" from the elements in serviceList
for (WebElement service : serviceList) {
    serviceIDs[i++] = service.getAttribute("value");
}

for (serviceID : serviceIDs) {
    if(!serviceID.contains("-")){
    String test = serviceID;
    System.out.println("Checking service name : " + serviceID + ",on page " + (baseUrl + "/en/account/service/"+serviceID) );

    driver.get(baseUrl + "/en/account/service/"+test);

    System.out.println("Service name : " + serviceID +"status : OK");

    }
    else{
    System.out.println("ERROR : INVALID SERVICE NAME");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes... during inspiration smoking this idea also occured to me , but withou Your help i coulnd solve this issue thank you very much.